# UIView out of bounds opaque

Tags: objective-c, uiview, shadow, quartz-core

i'm try to do something like this:

[image: a]!

I've used QuartzCore, but it's not working.

What i did:

1- create UIView `clipSubviews = NO;`

2- added an imaveview that can i move and scale;

3- added another view behind the first view;

But it's not working.

Does anyone know how can i do something like the image?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think @Nathan is asking for code to perform a crop.  I think the question is how to do the nested transparency effect.

Comment: @Nathan if my interpretation of your question is correct, there are a few ways you could approach it.  What version of iOS are you targeting?  This should be very easy to do with autolayout.  More work otherwise.